# Katalon IDE generated script gives error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, xpath, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCNAX.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp9Ga.png)

I am using Katalon IDE for generating a script.

As my application has a signout button on top right, when I click it, IDE will generate

```
xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='S'])[3]/following::span[3]
```

When running this in Eclipse this line gives an error. On inspecting this element I found this:

---

```
    <td id="titlebar_hyperlink_8-co_0" role="presentation" 
    nowrap="nowrap" align="left" class="  verticalSpacer" 
    style="vertical-align:top;">
    <span id="titlebar_hyperlink_8-lbsignout" align="left" 
    ctype="label" tabindex="0" targetid=
    "titlebar_hyperlink_8-lbsignout" mxevent="click" accesskey="S" 
    class="text powerwhite   anchor" style="display:block;cursor:pointer;" 
    title="Sign Out ALT+S" hotkey="83"><img id="titlebar_hyperlink_8- 
    lbsignout_image" src="btn_signout.gif" class="pwimg" border="0" 
    style="vertical-align:top;margin:0px;margin-left:3px;margin-right:3px;" 
    alt="Sign Out ALT+S"><span><span></span><span class="text hl 
    hlak">S</span><span>ign Out</span></span></span></td>
```

I'm new to selenium and all its related stuff. I would appreciate any kind of help on this. Thanks, Stack Overflow Community.

[inspecting Signout element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnwRv.png)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: your xpath is wrong, please change the xpath and work on it

Comment: @vel  how can i extact right path from xml....i m totally new to this..srry for asking this basic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the xpath to

```
'.//*[@title="Sign Out ALT+S"]'
```

**Explanation:**

You want to uniquely locate an element. Usually, you would try with the `id`, but the id of your element seems dynamic so it might not work in every case.

`*` - this means any element, and inside of the brackets `[ ]` you put the attribute you want to find the element by. I chose title because it will probably be unique on a given page.

I recommend [this cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath) for xpath reference.

Comment: thnks mate...it works like a charm...still m nt able to get its logic..can u plz help me to understand this

Comment: You want to uniquely locate an element. Usually, you would try with "id", but the id of your element seems dynamic so it might not work in every case. `*` - this means any element, and inside of the brackets `[ ]` you put the attribute you want to find the element by. I chose `title` because it will probably be unique on a given page.